# Sorting a dynamically populated list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a list box that is dynamically populated by a user with a value made up of a pipe delimited value and a name.  I do a check using the key to make sure the same value is not added twice but after that I want to sort the remaining list.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function storeaccount(name, account, accountName, Nom)
    var count = 0;
    var key = name + "|" +  account + "|" + accountName + "|" + Nom;
    var listBox = document.getelementbyid(listbox);    
    for(var i = 0; i < listBox.options.length; i++){
        if(listBox.options[i].value == key)
        { count++;
        }
    }

    if (count < 0) {
        $('<%listbox.clientid%>')append('<option value="' + key + '"> + name + '</option>
    }
```

How do I sort listbox by name whilst keeping the key intact to use in my duplicate check using jQuery?

Comment: your code will never go into this condition `if (count < 0){` your count is either `0` or greater than `0` ... And could you clarify your question

Comment: Sorry it is meant to say < 1,  I have retyped quickly that bit works fine, any comment on how to sort?  Thanks

Comment: Can you not use JS sort() method?

Comment: Can I clarify my question?  How do I sort the Listbox using jquery in my example above?

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct, you want to sort the listbox alphabetically. You are also performing a duplicate check using JS.

I would say, leave everything that you have done as it is and perform the sort operation on top of it after your duplicate checking process is done (like 2 loosely integrated processes).

**Here's how you perform sort on list-box:**

```
    function SortList(listname) { 
        var $r = $(listname + " option"); 
        $r.sort(function(a, b) { 
            return (a.value < b.value) ? -1 : (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : 0;
        // if you do not have value attribute for option use the text value. Replace the above line of code with the one below.
        //return (a.value < b.value) ? -1 : (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : 0;
        }); 
        $($r).remove(); 
        $(listname).append($($r)); 
    }
```

And, then invoke the function:

```
SortList('#Id_Of_Listbox');
```

Here's jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2bg/2/

Comment: yes that is what I want to do, so I take it I just pass ListBox from my example to your function Sortist

Comment: Yes just pass in the ID of your list box to the function. Answer updated.

Comment: unfortunitely that does not seem to work for me? It calls the method, and runs successfully but my list is not sorted afterwards.  I tried to step through using debugger but it dives off into a JQuery library where I can't follow what is going on

Comment: Also, it is possible that you do not have values for listbox option. If not use text property of option instead of value. like a.text < b.text. see updated answer.

Comment: maybe my call was wrong, I used SortList(ListBox) I see your example has a ('#Id_Of_Listbox') what should that be in my example?

Comment: So, whats id the ID of your Select element?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33573/discussion-between-apw-and-learner)